# Snakemake - How to use every line of input file as wildcard

Tags: python, snakemake

I am pretty new to using Snakemake and I have looked around on SO to see if there is a solution for the below - I am almost very close to a solution, but not there yet.

I have a single column file containing a list of SRA ids and I want to use snakemake to define my rules such that every SRA id from that file becomes a parameter on command line.

```
#FileName = Samples.txt
Samples
SRR5597645
SRR5597646
SRR5597647
```

Snakefile below:

```
from pathlib import Path
shell.executable("bash")
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import shutil

configfile: "config.json"

data_dir=os.getcwd()

units_table = pd.read_table("Samples.txt")
samples= list(units_table.Samples.unique())

#print(samples)

rule all:
    input:
           expand("out/{sample}.fastq.gz",sample=samples)

rule clean:
     shell: "rm -rf .snakemake/"

include: 'rules/download_sample.smk'
```

download_sample.smk

```
rule download_sample:
    """
    Download RNA-Seq data from SRA.
    """
    input: "{sample}"
    output: expand("out/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=samples)
    params:
        outdir = "out",
        threads = 16
    priority:85
    shell: "parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {input} --threads {params.threads} --outdir {params.outdir}  --gzip "
```

I have tried many different variants of the above code, but somewhere I am getting it wrong.

What I want: For every record in the file Samples.txt, I want the parallel-fastq-dump command to run. Since I have 3 records in Samples.txt, I would like these 3 commands to get executed

```
parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id SRR5597645 --threads 16 --outdir out --gzip
```

```
parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id SRR5597646 --threads 16 --outdir out --gzip
```

```
parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id SRR5597647 --threads 16 --outdir out --gzip
```

This is the error I get

```
snakemake -np
WildcardError in line 1 of rules/download_sample.smk:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'sample'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `input` section of a rule must refer to file (or patterns that can refer to files once wildcards have been substituted by the corresponding values). Snakemake needs this because it connects rules based on the files that they need (`input` section) and produce (`output` section). The SRA id cannot belong to the `input` section, because it is not a file. It could be in the parameter section, but it seems that you do not need this here, because the SRA id simply corresponds to the `{sample}` wildcard, which you can directly use in the `shell` section (see @dariober's answer).

Comment: Thanks @dariober - Your solution worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that what you need is to access the `sample` wildcard using the `wildcards` object:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("out/{sample}_fastq.gz", sample=samples)

rule download_sample:
    output: 
        "out/{sample}_fastq.gz"
    params:
        outdir = "out",
        threads = 16
    priority:85
    shell:"parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {wildcards.sample} --threads {params.threads} --outdir {params.outdir}  --gzip "
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution could be to use the `run:` section of the rule instead of the `shell:`. This allows you to employ python code:

```
rule download_sample:
    # ...
    run:
        for input_file in input:
            shell(f"parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {input_file} --threads {params.threads} --outdir {params.outdir} --gzip")
```

This straightforward solution however is not idiomatic. From what I can see, you have a one-to-one relationship between input samples and output files. In other words to produce one `out/{sample}_fastq.gz` file you need a single `{sample}`. The best solution would be to reduce your rule to the one that makes a single file:

```
rule download_sample:
    input: "{sample}"
    output: "out/{sample}_fastq.gz"
    params:
        outdir = "out",
        threads = 16
    priority:85
    shell: "parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {input} --threads {params.threads} --outdir {params.outdir} --gzip "
```

The rule `all:` now requires all targets; the rule `download_sample` downloads a single sample, the Snakemake workflow does the rest: it constructs a graph of dependences and creates one instance of the rule `download_sample` per sample. Moreover, if you wish it can run these rules in parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution makes sense, but I get an error.

```Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:'sample'```

Also, to clarify, every line in my {input_file} is an individual command on the shell

To clarify, if I have ```sample_a``` and ```sample_b``` as the 2 lines in my input_file ```Samples.txt```, then there will be 2 different shell commands:

```parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id sample_a .....```

```parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id sample_b .....```

Comment: I provided you 2 solutions, which one produces an error? Please update your question.

Comment: Solution 2 produces the error (I would need something similar to Solution 2 as I intend to run it in parallel).

I also see something similar in this SO question which looks unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946235/snakemake-error-when-trying-to-generate-multiple-output-files

Comment: @user10101904, please show full example of the code that produces the error.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the code and errors. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @user10101904, please study my solution precisely. You don't need to expand the output.

Comment: Dmitry - sorry I misinterpreted and I expanded my input. Even your answer works but because of SO rules I think I can only mark 1 answer correct. 

Thanks Dmitry